# Encoding of umlauts with the android pdf writer lib

Tags: java, android, pdf, encoding, character-encoding

I'm using the [Android PDF Writer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/) and I'm still confused. My PDF Renderer have to write words with umlauts ('ß', 'Ä', 'Ü') and they doesn't appear correctly in the pdf.

I think the issue is with the method `getBytes(String encoding)` from the String class.

```
PDFWriter pdfWriter = new PDFWriter(PaperSize.A4_WIDTH, PaperSize.A4_HEIGHT);
pdfWriter.setFont(StandardFonts.SUBTYPE, StandardFonts.SANS_SERIF, StandardFonts.MAC_ROMAN_ENCODING);
// only write some strings into the pdfwriter
parseData(pdfWriter);
outputToFile(filename, pdfWriter.asString(), "UTF-8");
```

When I inspect the pdfWriter.asString() the umlauts are present.

```
private void outputToFile(String fileName, String pdfContent, String encoding) {
    File newFile = new File(fileName);
    Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, newFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        newFile.createNewFile();
        try {
            FileOutputStream pdfFile = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
            pdfFile.write(pdfContent.getBytes("UTF8"));
            pdfFile.close();
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            //
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a problem within the getBytes() method?

Comment: You should consider that PDF library a proof-of-concept but not yet ready for production use. it has numerous deficiencies, your encoding issue being one of them but even worse the generated PDFs are invalid in some respects. PDF viewers do not normally complain but as soon as your PDFs are post-proceeded by other software, these errors usually pop up.

Comment: Probably the best is to develop for an higher android api with the native pdf support. Otherwise Karol S helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the answer before your very nose: Your PDF doesn't use UTF-8, so the PDF viewer tries to decode your UTF-8 encoded file as MacRoman.

For a quick fix you can use `StandardEncodings.WIN_ANSI_ENCODING` on one side and `"WINDOWS-1252"` or `"ISO-8859-1"` on the other.

Comment: Thank you. On this problem I waste a half day of my life.

Comment: This might break PDF cross references in the file at hand. On the other hand they are broken by this library anyway... ;)