# Itext show empty line for Arabic words

Tags: android, pdf, itext, arabic, persian

I am using `Itext` to create `pdf` files in android using below code:

```
 Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(root.getPath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".pdf"));
                document.open();
                Font chapterFont = FontFactory.getFont("", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC);
                Font paragraphFont = FontFactory.getFont("", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 12, Font.NORMAL);

                Chunk chunk = new Chunk(b.getTitle(), chapterFont);

                Chapter chapter = new Chapter(new Paragraph(chunk), 1);
                chapter.setNumberDepth(0);
                chapter.add(new Paragraph(b.getLead(), paragraphFont));
                document.add(chapter);
                document.close();
```

when i use english words it works fine, but when i use `arabic` or `persian` words it shows empty lines,

what is the problem? and how can i solve it?
thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you actually using `""` as your font?

Comment: yes, it works for english words

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31358327/231316)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem fixed by changing this line:

```
Font chapterFont = FontFactory.getFont("", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC);
```

to

```
Font chapterFont = FontFactory.getFont("assets/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 16, Font.BOLDITALIC);
```

Answer (score 2):

step 1 - add font:

```
Font font= FontFactory.getFont("assets/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 16, Font.NORMAL);
```

step 2 - add table (in my case) :

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        table.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);

        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("بستانکار",font)));
```

and for RTL use :

```
setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL) .
```

you can use this method in PdfWriter too;

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a encoding issue, Make sure the default enconding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Alright, check what's it default encoding, then write the chapter with the right encoding... look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564230/encoding-of-umlauts-with-the-android-pdf-writer-lib

Comment: The file is a binary file. Thus, no encoding for the `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: @mkl You right, the stream output file shall not be changed, the local default shall be. I need forgot to update it. Anyway, it could also be a font problem as another answers shows.